# Events/Activities Crossword Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, crosswords

I wonder where such events/activities happen.
Mind the gaps while filling!

[image]

The crossword grid was created at
https://worksheets.theteacherscorner.net/make-your-own/crossword/
The idea of the puzzle belongs to me

---

Hint 1:

> A ballad of hot and cold!

---

Hint 2:

> Sigils and their locations.

Comment: Did you make this puzzle?

Comment: Yes. May I know why you're asking? @bobble

Comment: Puzzles which were made by someone else need to be attributed, but if it is original that is attribution enough

Comment: One piece of friendly feedback for you, since I know you're keen to learn: Usually setters tend to wait 24 hours before adding hints to a puzzle on PSE, as this is a global community and that gives members from all around the world a chance to see your puzzle in its original intended form. Also, although you might not be getting an immediate answer, many people (like myself, quite often) will be thinking about it from time to time, and eventually inspiration might strike without needing further hints. Maybe leave it a couple of days between further hint edits - give it time :)

Comment: @Stiv OK. Thanks for the feedback. I'll surely keep this in mind

Comment: I have a fair idea of what we're looking at but it seems it will require a lot of Googling. If you're looking to give a hint in the near future, I recommend giving the enumeration of the clues.

Comment: @Sid Sure. Point taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are

> [House Sigils in Game of Thrones](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Heraldry) and the castles these houses call home.

Solutions and Explanations:

> 1: Stag -> House Baratheon -> **Storm's end**
>  2: Dragon -> House Targaryen -> **Dragonstone**
>  3: Lion -> House Lannister -> **Casterly Rock**
>  4: Rose -> House Tyrell -> **Highgarden**
>  5: A spear in the sun -> House Martell -> **Sunspear**
>  6: Not a sigil but the capital -> King's Landing -> **Sunspear**
>  7: Trout -> House Tully -> **Riverrun**
>  8: Direwolf -> House Stark -> **Winterfell**
>  9: Kraken -> House Greyjoy -> **Pyke**
>  10: Falcon -> House Arryn -> **The Eyrie**

Full grid:

> [image]